# Axios not parsing JSON but returning all the markup on page using React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I have a local .json file that I am trying to fetch but instead all the markup for my page is being returned. I've scoured online looking for a solution, but coming up short.

flickrActions.js:

```
export const fetchFlickr = () => {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
   axios.get("../data/output.json")
    .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_FLICKR_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_FLICKR_REJECTED", payload: err})
      })
   }
}
```

output.json:

```
[
   {
      "code":"BAcyDyQwcXX",
      "id":"1161022966406956503",
      "display_src":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xap1/t51.2885-15/e35/12552326_495932673919321_1443393332_n.jpg"
   },
   {
      "code":"BAcyDyQwcXX",
      "id":"1161022966406956503",
      "display_src":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xap1/t51.2885-15/e35/12552326_495932673919321_1443393332_n.jpg"
   },
   {
      "code":"BAcyDyQwcXX",
      "id":"1161022966406956503",
      "display_src":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xap1/t51.2885-15/e35/12552326_495932673919321_1443393332_n.jpg"
   }
]
```

What is being returned:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  <body>
    <div id="main"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried passing a custom header to your request?
axios.get('../data/output.json', {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }, 
   data: {}
})

Comment: Also please note that the URL to requsted data should be relative to URL from which request is sent (e.g. `localhost`) not to the file with request code (`flickrActions.js` in your case). So maybe try  `axios.get("/data/output.json")` if `data` folder is at same level that `index.html`

Comment: @BorisAblamunits - Thanks, but still no luck.

Comment: @BartekFryzowicz - Yeah, still no luck. I have the output in a data folder inside a dist folder. The index is at the root inside the dist folder. I would think "/data/output.json" would resolve but its still returning the same thing. I've update the question with what I am being returned.

Comment: Do you have a development server running that is it set to redirect all traffic to root?

Comment: @Lee - Yes. I am running express. I do however wonder if it has something to do with my config. Fetching outside of my localhost works.